# How the principal submatrix of a PSD matrix could be positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Assuming $A \in R^{n \times n}$ and is PSD and hermitian, so it has $k$ non-zero eigenvalues and $k<n$. Also its entries are all non-zero values.

Then i create $B$ as the principal submatrix of $A$ obtained by selecting same rows and columns of $A$ indicated by $I$, a subset of $\{1,2,...n\}$.

I noticed for a wide range of random matrices of $A$, as long as having $size(I)<k$ the resulted $B$ will be positive-definite meaning it has only positive eigenvalues. To generate $A$ i chose each entry as a random number in the range [-100 100] and doing $A^T*A$ and afterwards making some of the eigenvalues equal to zero  using eigenvalue decomposition of $A$.

So although it is possible to create specific matrices $A$ which don't obey the above rule, i think there should be some pre-conditions on $A$ to let the above happens! and i like to find the mathematical way to explain that!

Comment: A point of terminology : you should say that $B$ is the _submatrix_ of $A$ obtained by selecting lines and columns indicated by $I$, a subset of $\{1,2,...n\}$ if $A \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}.$

Comment: Could you say how you generate random (symmetric) positive semi-definite matrices ? I understand that you use matrices of the form $A=100*rand(n)$, but you do a certain processing afterwards, like taking $AA^T$ instead of $A$, don't you ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: yes i do the $A A^T$ thing as my matrices in my problem are also created based on that!

Comment: @JeanMarie: BTW, i manually made some of the eigenvalues equal to zero  using eigenvalue decomposition of $A$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $k=1$, $n=2$.

Let $I=\{2\}$, then $B=0$ which is not positive definite.

Edit:

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 8 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ 0.1 & 6 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \\ 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1\end{bmatrix}$. It has $k=3$ non-zero eigenvalues.  Let $I = \{ 3,4\}$, the matrix $B$ is singular.

Comment: Yes it is not applicable to diagonal matrices, but i tried that with random PSD matrices having nonzero entries and the numerical results always support the hypothesis. I'd edit the question to exclude the trivial case.

Comment: I just edited the question. :-)

Comment: What about $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2  & 2\\ 2 & 1 & 1\\2 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ when you suppress first row and first column ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: your matrix is not PSD!

Comment: ok, my observation cannot be applied to all PSD matrices, but i think there should be a criteria to let my observations happen, especially when $A$ doesn't have a specific structure like your example. I want to find that criteria!

Comment: @Bob OK, my bad. Here is a semi-definite positive matrix$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1  & 1\\1 & 2 & 2\\1 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ such that, when you suppress the first line and column, you are still with a semi-definite... not a definite.

Answer (score 0):

Two facts :

1) By the Cauchy interlacing theorem, the eigenvalues of any principal submatrix $((n-1) \times (n-1))$ $B$ of a Hermitian matrix $(n \times n)$ $A$ interlace those of $A$ (obtained by deleting a single row and a single column, with the same index). It means that if we are with a matrix $A$, the smallest eigenvalue of $B$ is $\geq$ to the smallest eigenvalue of initial matrix $A$. Continuing in this way, by an immediate recurrence, the smallest eigenvalue of a matrix of the type you consider (deleting the same $p$ rows and $p$ columns) will generate a smallest eigenvalue $\geq$ to the smallest eigenvalue of initial matrix $A$.

2) the determinant is the product of eigenvalues ; having no eigenvalue equal to $0$ is equivalent to $\det(A)\neq 0$.

Thus, as a consequence of 1) and 2), we just have to prove that :

$$\text{measure}(\{A \ | \ \det(A)\neq 0\})=1$$

(replace "measure" with "probability" ; it is the same meaning).

But, seen in $\mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$, the set of all $A$ such that $\det(A)=0$ is a hypersurface, thus with measure equal to 0. That's all.

---

An example: consider

- the set $\frak{E}$ of $2 \times 2$ symmetric definite positive matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ b & c \end{bmatrix}$$
(assimilable to $\mathbb{R}^3$) are defined by $a>0$ and $\det(A)=ac-b^2>0$.

- the set $\frak{F}$ of semi-definite positive matrices are defined by condition $\det(A)=ac-b^2=0$. It is the equation of a surface (which has a conical aspect, considered in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

$\frak{F}$ has measure 0 in $\frak{E}\cup\frak{F}$ (it is its frontier).

Look at the Matlab program below and its resulting image:

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;
> for k=1:2000;
>    A=rand(2);A=A*A';
>    S(:,k)=[A(1,1);A(2,1);A(2,2)];
> end
> plot3(S(1,:),S(2,:),S(3,:),'.b');
> [a,c]=meshgrid(0:0.02:2,0:0.02:2);
> surf(a,sqrt(a.*c),c,'edgecolor','none');alpha(0.3);
> view([131,40])
> ```

[image]